# radgridview bool columns are coming in as textbox instead of checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

All my new rows added to a radgridview from telerik are coming in as textbox instead of checkbox.
Can anyone tell me why or atleast give me code to convert it in c#

Code is like this:

```
 var qry = Settings.DbContext.OAdbContext.Sp_Temp(id).ToList();
radgridview1.DataSource = qry.ToList();
```

and in qry, I have a bool property that is showing up False and True instead of checkbox.  When I debug, column info shows me GridViewTextBoxColumn

Comment: Folks would need to see your radgridview1 setup as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help us better understand and resolve your issue, it'd be good if you can provide the markup code so that we can see what's been done on the UI.

The Telerik RadGridView control handles it naturally and all you need to do is to make sure the column is bound to the correct data member with the correct data type.

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
       <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding YourBooleanTypeMember}" />
   </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Comment: it was a very random thing.  basically, telerik stores the markup code locally on your machine, so a while ago I changed it to store the markup xml as a string in the database (in order to allow users to save grid settings and have it maintain them when logging in from other computers.)    For some reason, the new field was being added before the settings were and thus being added with default: <telerik:GridViewTextBoxColumn.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a CheckBox Column: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/columntypes/checkbox-column

Or you can use a template:
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/celltemplate-and-celledittemplate

I don't believe the GridView Column will figure out that bool means checkbox automatically.

Comment: thanks. but something is not right because even when I add manually a checkbox column it's also being shown as textbox!  Can I cast it myself in c# code?   foreach (GridViewRowInfo dr in radgridview1.Rows)....

Comment: You might want to show the code for this before  the downvotes start rolling in.